# PHP: get keys of independent arrays

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

I have two arrays.

Example of the first array:

```
$arrayOne = array
(
    'fruit' => array(
        'apples' => array(),
        'oranges' => array(),
        'bananas' => array()
    ),
    'vegetables' => array(
        'tomatoes' => array(),
        'carrots' => array(),
        'celery' => array(),
        'beets' => array
        (
            'bears' => array(),
            'battlestar-galactica' => array()
        ),
    ),
    'meat' => array(),
    'other' => array()
);
```

2nd:

```
$arrayTwo = array
(
    'frewt' => array(
        'aplz' => array(),
        'orangeez' => array(),
        'bunanahs' => array()
    ),
    'vetchteblz' => array(
        'toem8ohs' => array(),
        'careodds' => array(),
        'sell-R-e' => array(),
        'beats' => array
        (
            'bare z' => array(),
            'tablestar-neglectia' => array()
        ),
    ),
    'neat' => array(),
    'mother' => array()
);
```

Notice that the two arrays are in the exact same "format" (same number of dimensions, number of keys, order, etc., etc.), only the names of the keys differ. (The array keys basically hold all the data.)

I have a few variables that address the keys of the first array (`$arrayOne`). E.g. `$one` would address the first dimension of the first array, so it's value (string) would be one out of `'fruit'`, `'vegetables'`, `'meat'` or `'other'`.
`$two` would be `'apples'` or `'oranges'` or `'bananas'` or `'tomatoes'` or `'carrots'`,  etc., you get the idea. (There's vars for each dimension)
As I said, those variables only address `$arrayOne`. I want to be able to address the keys in the second array too, though. Meaning, by looking at the value of `$one` I want to be able to get the array_key of both arrays.

Comment: How do you want to handle the case where an array key happens multiple times in the first array?

Comment: That shouldn't matter, as identical keys will translate to the same keys in the second array. E.g. twice the key 'oranges' will be twice in the second array too, as 'orangeez'. I only really need the string of the appropriate keys of the second array.

Comment: OK, my solution stops searching after it finds the first key, but it's trivial to modify to return the positions for all the keys.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$arrayOne = //...

$arrayTwo = //...

function getPosition(array $arr, $key) {
    $it = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($arr),
        RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
    $pos = array();
    foreach ($it as $k => $v) {
        if (count($pos) - 1 > $it->getDepth()) {
            array_pop($pos);
            $pos[$it->getDepth()]++;
        }
        elseif (count($pos) - 1 < $it->getDepth()) {
            array_push($pos, 0);
        }
        else {
            $pos[$it->getDepth()]++;
        }
        if ($k === $key) {
            return $pos;
        }
    }
}

function getElementKey(array $arr, array $position) {
    $cur = $arr;
    $curkey = null;
    foreach ($position as $p) {
        reset($cur);
        for ($i = 0; $i < $p; $i++) {
            next($cur);
        }
        $curkey = key($cur);
        $cur = current($cur);
    }
    return $curkey;
}

var_dump(getPosition($arrayOne, "battlestar-galactica"));
var_dump(getElementKey($arrayTwo, array(1, 3, 1)));
```

gives:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  int(1)
  [1]=>
  int(3)
  [2]=>
  int(1)
}
string(19) "tablestar-neglectia"
```

You can feed the result of `getPosition` to `getElementKey`:

```
getElementKey($arrayTwo, getPosition($arrayOne, "battlestar-galactica"));
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure how that helps? And there won't be a "here" value either, gonna be an empty array.

Comment: @tsha If you want the key and not the value, replace `return current($cur)` with `return key($cur)`. Then `getElement($arrayTwo, getPosition($arrayOne, "battlestar-galactica"));` would give `'tablestar-neglectia'`

Comment: Thanks, but I couldn't get it to work. Could you please edit your post and show me? Maybe even test it? Would be great! Thanks.

Comment: This does work however I found when I got to a depth greater than 2 it meant the next element at the top level got duplicated. However adding a second array_pop($pos); below where it already does it seemed to fix everything! Thanks for the solution though saved me time!

Answer (score 0):

Check out [array_keys](http://in.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) from both arrays and then map the positions. Like array_keys for your arrays will give you -

```
$arrayKeyOne = array('fruit', 'vegetables', 'meat', 'other');
$arrayKeyTwo = array('frewt', 'vetchteblz', 'meat', 'mother');
```

Then a $arrayKeyTwo[array_search($one, $arrayKeyOne)] shuld give you what you want. Let know if this helps.