# PHP: find key position in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, path, multidimensional-array

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP: get keys of independent arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116970/php-get-keys-of-independent-arrays)

Hello.

I have a multi-dimensional array. I want a function that finds the position of the given array key (all my array keys are strings) and then returns the position of the key as an array.

E.g:

```
$arr = array
(
    'fruit' => array(
        'apples' => array(),
        'oranges' => array(),
        'bananas' => array()
    ),
    'vegetables' => array(
        'tomatoes' => array(),
        'carrots' => array(),
        'celery' => array(),
        'beets' => array
        (
            'bears' => array(),
            'battlestar-galactica' => array()
        ),
    ),
    'meat' => array(),
    'other' => array()
);
```

Now if I call the function like this:

```
theFunction('bears');
```

It should return:

```
array(1, 3, 0);
```

Comment: Seriously? I gave you an answer two days ago that does this exactly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116970/php-get-keys-of-independent-arrays/3117173#3117173 function `getPosition`.

Comment: What is the expected functionality in this example?
$arr=array('bears' => array('bears' => array('bears' => 5))); ?

Comment: Indeed you did, but your function didn't work properly for deeper multidimensional arrays, for whatever reason. The function below works.

Answer (score 2):

```
function array_tree_search_key($a, $subkey) {
   foreach (array_keys($a) as $i=>$k) {
      if ($k == $subkey) {
         return array($i);
      }
      elseif ($pos = array_tree_search_key($a[$k], $subkey)) {
         return array_merge(array($i), $pos);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works! But is it possible to only use the $subkey string as a param, and always use the same array? Can't seem to get that to work...