# PHP - Creating path list from array

Tags: php, arrays, tree

I have an array of id's which are formed into a tree structure, for a storage type application.

[image: Array image]

The tree structure is then displayed similar to this

[image]

What I am looking to do is create a list of the full path of each array element.

[366 => 'Files',356 => 'Misc',354 => 'Photos',368 = 'Photos/Cities',375 = 'Photos/Cities/England',376 = 'Photos/Cities/Scotland']

The menu is user defined so this is just an example, it could have many more levels.

The name for each array element is added from an array of names ie names[376] (Photos)

I have tried several recursive functions and struggled, I'm hopeing someone who is much better at PHP than me can help!
Thanks

Comment: not really a dupe, but very related, and maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3544988/how-to-get-hierarchy-path-of-an-element-in-an-array

Comment: Did you mean: [`recursion`](https://www.google.com/search?q=recursion)

Comment: Where do the folder names come from, are they in the "array of ids"?

Comment: The folder names come from another array of names ie $names[376] would be Photos

Comment: I'm not clear on the data. How the parent relationship is expressed. Did you write the render code because I'm guessing understanding that fully you would be able to answer your own question. Code or data? Otherwise just gonna suggest generic web [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116970/php-get-keys-of-independent-arrays/3117173#3117173)/[tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590662/walk-array-recursively-and-print-the-path-of-the-walk).

Comment: I did write the render code and understand the code, however I'm struggling with converting the render code into a list I can use in a select. I've done a fair amount of searching, I'll have to come back to it with a clear head ! thanks

Comment: ^ you will get it then!  Sharing that render code might help get an answer here.

Comment: Based on your menu shouldn't `$names[376] = 'Scotland'`?

Comment: Are they empty arrays at the bottom level e.g. 375, 356? or is there other data in them?

Comment: The bottom 2 are empty because they are at the base level of the tree and have no children. The html is rendered up side down, so 356/366 would be Files/Misc. I think $names[376] = 'Scotland' is right, although its only an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understand what you want to achieve. In that case, this could be a solution

```
<?php

$ids = [
  354 => [
    368 => [
      375,
      376
    ]
  ],
  356,
  366
];

$names = [
    354 => "Photos", 
    368 => "Cities",
    375 => "England",
    376 => "Scotland",
    356 => "Files",
    366 => "Misc"
];


print_r(build_list($ids));

function build_list($ids, $path = ""){
  global $names;
  $list = [];
  foreach($ids as $key => $value){
    if(is_array($value)){
      //$list[$key] = $path . $names[$key]; // uncomment if you need output (2)
      $list = array_replace_recursive($list, build_list($value, ($path . $names[$key] . "/")))
    }else{
      $list[$value] = $path . $names[$value];
    }
  }
  return $list;
}

?>
```

Output (1)

```
Array
(
  [375] => Photos/Cities/England
  [376] => Photos/Cities/Scotland
  [356] => Files
  [366] => Misc
)
```

Output (2)

```
Array
(
  [354] => Photos
  [368] => Photos/Cities
  [375] => Photos/Cities/England
  [376] => Photos/Cities/Scotland
  [356] => Files
  [366] => Misc
)
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it's kinda right apart from needing the array key to be the id of the last item in each array value...sorry not very clearArray
(
    [375] => Photos/Cities/England
    [376] => Photos/Cities/Scotland
    [356] => Files
    [366] => Misc
)

Comment: @user3459394 Check the edited answer. A bit late but at least you have two solutions

Answer (score 1):

This function will do what you want. It recursively traverses the tree, creating elements for each key and passing prefixes down through the recursion to create each element's name:

```
function make_paths($array, $names, $prefix = '') {
    $output = array();
    foreach ($array as $key => $arr) {
        $name = $prefix . ($prefix != '' ? '/' : '') . $names[$key];
        if (count($arr)) {
            $output = $output + make_paths($arr, $names, $name);
        }
        $output[$key] = $name;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

Output:

```
Array (
    [375] => Photos/Cities/England
    [376] => Photos/Cities/Scotland
    [368] => Photos/Cities
    [354] => Photos
    [356] => Misc
    [366] => Files 
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/bfrE2)

Comment: I'm curious as to why you decided to unaccept this answer? It gives exactly the same results as the later one.